# Why isn't my sound autoplaying in the background?

Tags: html

so i put it so whenever someone opens my webpage a background sound plays. The code I'm using works and has worked before on different projects but now, it doesn't. Can someone help me?
My code:

```
<div id="player">
    <audio autoplay hidden>
    <source src="./sounds/bgsound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        If you're reading this then your browser is outdated.
    </audio>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").autoplay;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try changing the src from `./sounds/bgsound.mp3` to `/sounds/bgsound.mp3`

Answer (score 1):

See [MDN's autoplay guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)

> The term autoplay refers to any feature that causes audio to begin to play without the user specifically requesting that playback begin.

and

> From the user's perspective, a web page or app that spontaneously starts making noise without warning can be jarring, inconvenient, or off-putting. Because of that, browsers generally only allow autoplay to occur successfully under specific circumstances.

---

"When the page loads" is not one of those specific circumstances (and is one of the *most* annoying times for autoplay to occur) so it is blocked by modern browsers.

Comment: Okay but is there a way to make it play when the website opens?

Comment: No. Web browsers block that (except under some very limited circumstances which the guide I linked to covers but which are unlikely to apply to your site).